# Impossible to set jQuery dialog option on ulterior calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let this jQuery dialog:

```
$('#myDialog').dialog
({
    //        …,
    buttons:
    [
    //      …,
     {
       id: "bOK",
       click: function () {  $(this).dialog("destroy"); }
    }
   ],
   open: Do_On_Open (),
    //      …
 });
```

and like so

```
function Do_On_Open ()
{
  // quite a few things here
  Center_Dialog ($('#myDialog') );
  // $(window).resize ( function () { $('#myDialog').dialog ( "option", "position",  gPosStd); });
 }
```

The *Center_Dialog* function replicates the next line that is commented in *Do_On_Open*, like so:

```
function Center_Dialog ( theDialog )
{
   $(window).resize ( function ()
   {
      theDialog.dialog ( "option", "position",  { my: "center top", at: "center-40 top+80", of: window });
    });
 }
```

On the first call to the dialog, everything is fine: *Center_Dialog* behaves as expected upon window-resizing. On ulterior calls, *Center_Dialog* aborts and the console returns an jQuery error: “cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'”.

In other words, the first call remains cached and lacks the object properties to apply to in order to complete successfully on ulterior calls —while purging the cache of the browser makes it serviceable again (for once!).

What is it I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I've tested your code. I am not sure, but I think, when you close the dialog, dialog has destroyed, so window.resize can not attach the option you gave.

I've just removed your two function and move it to the `open` method directly.

In this case, there are no errors.

```
open: function() {
    $(this).dialog("option", "position", {my: "center top", at: "center-40 top+80", of: window});
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to move the dialog, when window resized, then put this thing into a function, and check, is your dialog is visible or not:

```
$.fn.doSomething = function () {
    if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
        $(this).dialog("option", "position", {my: "center top", at: "center-40 top+80", of: window});
    }
};

$(window).resize(function () {
        $('#myDialog').doSomething();
});
```

and in the open method call this function:

```
open: function () {
    $(this).doSomething();
}
```

The key is to check, is your dialog visible.

Comment: I've just edited my code right now. Check it again. You can use as you do, just add this `if ($('#myDialog').is(":visible")) {` statement into your function. It could be the `theDialog` also.

Comment: Perfect. I am trying to get in touch through your blog, but it seems off-line —we might have something for you.

Comment: @BriceCoustillas Yeah, my blog is not available any more. I have other plans with my site.